# Method 'SQLitePlatformWinRT..ctor()' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in (method name in library)

Tags: uwp, sqlite.net

I have a UWP library project with `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform` and `Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`. Also the library project refers to the SQLite.Net-PCL library.
When I add my library project in my test App and run it, I get the following error :
`Method 'SQLitePlatformWinRT..ctor()' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in <method name in library> There may have been a missing assembly` .

Should the Sqlite classes be added in test app externally or some additional configurations are required.
I have never worked with runtime directives, so not sure if the error is related to some configuration in the same.

Comment: I created a UWP class library as what you described and a test app to reference it and run. Nothing wrong with it and it worked well. I cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide a [mcve] project. My UWP SDK version is 14393.

Comment: Did you add the SQLite library externally to your test app? Or it worked without adding any extensions or packages for SQLite?

Comment: No, I didn't add any SQLite library to the test app.